# Can not Archive and Unarchive file to Document Folder

Tags: objective-c, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

This code does not give any error but it's not creating the "plist" file nor reading from it.

I wrote a code that specifies the direct path to the folder and it creates and writes to the file although it cannot read from it.

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:employees toFile:@"/Users/Documents/employees.plist"];
```

This code below could Not write nor read the file.

And I followed it line by line to the online instructions.

I copied the exact `Employee.h` and `Employee.m` file and no error there either.

Thank you for your help.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "Employee.h"


NSString* getPropertyListPath() {

    NSURL *documentDir = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                         URLForDirectory:NSDocumentationDirectory
                                inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                       appropriateForURL:nil
                                  create:NO
                                   error:nil];

    NSURL *plist = [documentDir URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"EmployeeFile.plist"];

    return plist.path;

}



void createAndArchiveObjects (NSString *filePath) {

    NSLog(@"Creating objects manually");

    Employee *john = [[Employee alloc] init];

    [john setFirstName:@"A"];
    [john setLastName:@"J"];
    [john setEmployeeNumber:12345];
    [john setHireDate:[NSDate date]];

    NSMutableArray *employees = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [employees addObject:john];

    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:employees toFile:filePath];

    NSLog(@"Objects created and archived");
}



void unarchiveSavedObjects(NSString *filePath) {

    NSMutableArray *employees = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:filePath];

    for (Employee *e in employees) {
        NSLog(@"The unarchived, reconstituted object is %@", e);
    }
}



int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {


        NSString *path = getPropertyListPath();

        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {

            unarchiveSavedObjects(path);

        } else {

            createAndArchiveObjects(path);

        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

The `NSLog` displays:

```
Creating objects manually
Objects created and archived
```

But no file is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using NSDocumentationDirectory instead of NSDocumentDirectory.

Use.,

```
NSURL *documentDir = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                          URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                          inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                          appropriateForURL:nil
                          create:NO
                          error:nil];
```